# Hybris multi-tenant configuration conflicts

Tags: multi-tenant, sap-commerce-cloud

We are working on a multi-tenant configuration over Hybris 6.5.0.4,
With a separation of the extensions by tenants, lets say :

- tenant_france : frModelExt, frFacadeExt, frStroreFrontExt ...
- tenant_canada : caModelExt, caFacadeExt, caStroreFrontExt ...

The main issue found using this configuration, is :

**The loading of all extensions/project.properties into each tenant !!**
And only the project.properties (not *local_tenant_OTHER_TENANTS.properties*)

And sometimes, the properties of other tenants overrides those of the actual tenant.

Even when using the **forbidden.extensions** property, like so :

in *local_tenant_france.properties* file : 
`forbidden.extensions = caModelExt;caFacadeExt;caStroreFrontExt`

---

**The Workarround :** (looking for better solution)

Redefine all extensions/project.properties into the corresponding *local_tenant_TENANT.properties* file, to prevent the properties override from others tenants properties.